# Location of Hadoop Libjars

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am running a hadoop job on a cluster and passing some jars using -libjars option while running a hadoop job. I am not sure where I can find these jars on cluster. One more thing whether  these jars are copied from localmachine to cluster. Where I can find these jars on cluster

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Hadoop - The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021773.do)

> Copies the specified JAR files from the local filesystem (or any filesystem if a scheme is
>   specified)to the shared filesystem used bythe jobtracker (usually HDFS), and adds them
>   to the MapReduce task’s classpath. This option is a useful way of shipping JAR files that
>   a job is dependent on.

So, the specified files are copied from the local file system to HDFS and then to the mapper/reducer nodes in the classpath. Also, these files are replicated mapreduce.client.submit.file.replication number of times, which is defaulted to 10. The reason why it's replicated more than 3 times is because the file has to be distributed to all the required nodes.

Comment: as small addition: physically they lay in libs/ directory of task working dir